# Javascript: Convert image to base64 not complete?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to convert image to base64 but the value is not complete?

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" id="imageid" src="{{helper.photo_1}}" /> 
function getBase64Image(img) {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      return dataURL
}

var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("imageid"));
console.log(base64); // the value is not complete.
```

When I use the base64 to show image, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask..? Isn't your `base64` variable already outside the function? In addition, what do you mean by 'value is not complete'?

Comment: andrei in console base64 value will not be printed completely. you can try to render this base64 url with proper mimetype

Comment: @wentjun My bad. When base64 in console.log, the value is not complete. I needed the complete value

Comment: thank you for your response. @arpit May I know how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to download the image?

Comment: <img alt="" src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgo ...  " you have to check the mimetype i.e. data:image/ jpg or png or gif

Comment: @wentjun No sir. I am trying to change the the image file to base64. Coming from here <img crossorigin="anonymous" id="imageid" src="{{helper.photo_1}}" />

Comment: @arpit when I console.log this is the result data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU

Comment: Are you sure that's not a limit of the browser `console.log`? I mean, base64 are very very long, so your browser won't display all of it (it's still just for debugging! Why should you load MB and MB of content?)

Comment: But your base64 is complete, it's full and it's not truncated inside javascript. You can use it

Comment: @Cristian thank you for your response. Hmm if that's the case it should work fine. The funny thing is when I use the variable to pdfmake. It shows the width and height of the image but inside there is no image